# Simplifying partial derivative of cross-entropy function

Tags: statistics, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, machine-learning

How do I simplify:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
  \frac{\partial C}{\partial w_j} & = & -\frac{1}{n} \sum_x \left(
    \frac{y }{\sigma(z)} -\frac{(1-y)}{1-\sigma(z)} \right)
  \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial w_j} \tag{58}\\
 & = & -\frac{1}{n} \sum_x \left( 
    \frac{y}{\sigma(z)} 
    -\frac{(1-y)}{1-\sigma(z)} \right)\sigma'(z) x_j.
\tag{59}\end{eqnarray}$$

to

$$\begin{eqnarray}
  \frac{\partial C}{\partial w_j} & = & \frac{1}{n}
  \sum_x \frac{\sigma'(z) x_j}{\sigma(z) (1-\sigma(z))}
  (\sigma(z)-y).
\tag{60}\end{eqnarray}$$

to get:

$$\begin{eqnarray} 
  \frac{\partial C}{\partial w_j} =  \frac{1}{n} \sum_x x_j(\sigma(z)-y).
\tag{61}\end{eqnarray}
$$

where $$\sigma(z) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-zx}}$$

?

I end up with:
$$\begin{eqnarray} 
  \frac{\partial C}{\partial w_j} =  \frac{1}{n} \sum_x x_j(2\sigma(z)y - \sigma(z) - y).
\tag{61}\end{eqnarray}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial C}{\partial w_j} = -\frac{1}{n} \sum_x \left( 
    \frac{y(1-\sigma(z))}{\sigma(z)(1-\sigma(z))} 
    -\frac{\sigma(z)(1-y)}{\sigma(z)(1-\sigma(z))} \right)\sigma'(z) x_j. \\
= -\frac{1}{n} \sum_x \left( 
    \frac{y(1-\sigma(z))-\sigma(z)(1-y)}{\sigma(z)(1-\sigma(z))} 
     \right)\sigma'(z) x_j. \\
= -\frac{1}{n} \sum_x \left( 
    \frac{(y-y \sigma(z))-(\sigma(z)-y \sigma(z))}{\sigma(z)(1-\sigma(z))} 
     \right)\sigma'(z) x_j. \\
= -\frac{1}{n} \sum_x \left( 
    \frac{(y-y \sigma(z))+(-\sigma(z)+y \sigma(z))}{\sigma(z)(1-\sigma(z))} 
     \right)\sigma'(z) x_j. \\
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_x \left( 
    \frac{-(y-y \sigma(z))+-(-\sigma(z)+y \sigma(z))}{\sigma(z)(1-\sigma(z))} 
     \right)\sigma'(z) x_j. \\
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_x \left( 
    \frac{(-y+y \sigma(z))+(\sigma(z)-y \sigma(z))}{\sigma(z)(1-\sigma(z))} 
     \right)\sigma'(z) x_j. \\
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_x \left( 
    \frac{-y+y \sigma(z)+\sigma(z)-y \sigma(z)}{\sigma(z)(1-\sigma(z))} 
     \right)\sigma'(z) x_j. \\
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_x \left( 
    \frac{-y+y \sigma(z)-y \sigma(z)+\sigma(z)}{\sigma(z)(1-\sigma(z))} 
     \right)\sigma'(z) x_j. \\
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_x \left( 
    \frac{-y+\sigma(z)}{\sigma(z)(1-\sigma(z))} 
     \right)\sigma'(z) x_j. \\
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_x \left( 
    \frac{\sigma(z)-y}{\sigma(z)(1-\sigma(z))} 
     \right)\sigma'(z) x_j. \\
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_x \left( 
    \frac{(\sigma(z)-y)\sigma'(z) x_j}{\sigma(z)(1-\sigma(z))} 
     \right). \\
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_x \left( 
    \frac{(\sigma(z)-y)\sigma'(z) x_j}{\sigma(z)(1-\sigma(z))} 
     \right). \\
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_x \left( 
    (\sigma(z)-y) x_j 
     \right). \\
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_x \left (
    x_j(\sigma(z)-y)  
     \right). \\
    \end{eqnarray}$$

since $$ \sigma(z)(1-\sigma(z)) = \sigma'(z)$$